# Passport authentication not finding local strategy

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, endpoint

I am currently using passport to authenticate users for my application, however passport.authenticate does not call my local Passport Strategy.

Here is my `auth.js` which is where my endpoint is for the user to login.

[auth.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMZ1E.png)

Here is Passport.js where my LocalStrategy is located.

[passport.js pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XVkt.png)
[passport.js pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRsyG.png)

The endpoint always returns the status 400 with the message "Hold up somethings off." because the User is always returned as false
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried deleting the code completely off of my local and redownloading it off of GitHub. This was a nuclear option but I couldn't think of anything else to do.

Comment: Do the `console.log` print out correct ?

Comment: unfortunately the console. log did as far as I can tell.

Comment: I mean the `console.log(username, password)`. If it don't print correctly then there's something wrong on your client side. Your backend code looks fine.